# Using MockClientHttpResponse with HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to test custom response error handler.

I have overridden method:

```java
@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) {
    HttpStatus status = getHttpStatusCode(response);

    switch(status.series()) {
        //my logic here
    }
}
```

from `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`
that checks for `HttpStatus.Series`

How can I make use of `MockClientHttpResponse`?

When trying like below:

```java
ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse = 
    new MockClientHttpResponse(new byte[]{}, HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR);
```

I obviously get an error:
`Cannot resolve constructor 'MockClientHttpResponse(byte[], org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.Series)'`

If I cannot use that mock, how else can I nicely create an object of `ClientHttpResponse` with `Series`?

Comment: You don't. You need to set the code not the series. So you need to set an internal server error (500) or the likes.

Comment: Thank you! Really simple, shame I could not find it.